# MVC2.0 read textbox and add value to text area on same view

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

i have form where i have text box value and link (add). when user enteres data in to textbox and click add it should add entered text to textArea on the same view. I  have tried doing this with ajax.actionlink but i can't seem to figure out how too pass the entered text to parameter. can anyone have another idea that i can try..i can't use Ajax.beginForm because i have html form already.

Thank you in advance.

here is html code that i have so far with ajax action link.

```
                    <div class="editor-label">
                        <%: Html.Label("DefectID / FeatureID")%> <%: Html.TextBox("DefectID", "", new { @class = "required" })%> <%: Ajax.ActionLink("Add", "InsertDefectIDs", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "DefectIds" }) %><%--<input type="button" name="add" value="Add" />--%>
                    </div>

                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.DefectIds, new { rows = 5, cols = 12, @readonly = "true" })%>
                        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DefectIds)%>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Does the user input need to be sent to the server for when the user clicks add if your end goal is to populate a textarea field? You can do this a lot easier with javascript on the client side. Please help us understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I tried doing this with javascript with no success. Yes.. my final goal is to populate the text area field. i do not need to go to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to something like the following:

HTML

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <%: Html.Label("DefectID / FeatureID")%> 
    <%: Html.TextBox("DefectID", "", new { @class = "required" })%> 
    <input type="button" name="add" value="Add" onclick="AddDefectId();" />
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
    <%: Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.DefectIds, new { rows = 5, cols = 12, @readonly = "true" })%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DefectIds)%>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddDefectId() {
        var defectId = document.getElementById('DefectId').value;

        if(defectId != "")
             document.getElementById('DefectIds').value += defectId + ","

        document.getElementById('DefectId').value = "";        
    }​
</script>
```

Here is a straight html/javascript example: http://jsfiddle.net/zJpRA/6/